# Dyanamically set size of textbox using js

Tags: javascript, html

I have to define a textbox in html whose maximum size should be 3.
Now If I am entring -100 then these are 4 characters but I want that user should allow  to enter 100 or -100. If I define size="3" then it will not allow -100. So I want to know can we define size of the textbox dynamically,i.e. if I enter "-" sign then size will increase to 4 else it should be 3.

Can we do this using js?

Comment: As a comment I'd suggest you to avoid constraining typing in a field. This is not going to really help (people can for example think they've a problem with the keyboard) and will only make the experience worse. Adding a red label appearing above or below the field saying "value must be between -100 and 100 inclusive" is a good idea that will enhance the user experience. Blocking my typing is instead going to make me just hate your forms. Remember that you only have one chance to give a good first impression, don't annoy users unless you really really must.

Comment: sorry,,,, i got your suggsetions

Answer (score 1):

Call this function on the key down event of the text box

```
function check(e){

  var unicode=e.charCode? e.charCode : e.keyCode

  if(if unicode==109){
   //increase the size of text box to 4;
  }

}
```

Comment: but how i acn set the size=4?

Comment: Maybe with `e.target.setAttribute("size", "4");`

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions in a keydown event: If the regexp doesn't match, the function returns FALSE.

Possible regular expression:

```
^[-]{0,1}\d{0,3}$
```

Comment: but how it will detect the size?

Comment: actually I want to restrict the user max to -999 or he can max enter 999

Comment: sorry to misunderstand you for -100 or 100

Comment: 1.) For the size you can use `if (this.value.length==4) this.size=4;`
2.) Test the regex for example [here](http://regexpal.com/). That works fine for me.

Comment: Do you want the highest number to be 100 and the smallest one to be -100?
You also can use the JS function `parseInt()` and check whether the number is less than 0.

Comment: nups -100 n 100 are just examples.max can be 999 and min can be -999